# Spark Dataframe groupBy with sequence as keys arguments

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataFrame and I want to aggregate values by multiple keys

As spark documentation suggests:

> def groupBy(col1: String, cols: String*): GroupedData Groups the
>   DataFrame using the specified columns, so we can run aggregation on them

So I do the following

```
 val keys = Seq("a", "b", "c")
 dataframe.groupBy(keys:_*).agg(...)
```

Intellij Idea throws me following errors:

> 1. expansion for non repeated parameters
> 2. Type mismatch: expected  Seq[Column], actual Seq[String]

However, I can pass multiple arguments manually without errors:

```
dataframe.groupBy("a", "b", "c").agg(...)
```

So, my question is: How can I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either use columns with `groupBy(cols: Column*)`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val keys = Seq("a", "b", "c").map(col(_))
dataframe.groupBy(keys:_*).agg(...)
```

or `head` / `tail` with `groupBy(col1: String, cols: String*)`:

```
val keys = Seq("a", "b", "c") 
dataframe.groupBy(keys.head, keys.tail: _*).agg(...)
```